# Best way to access a read-only list of strings?

Tags: java, android, windows

I've got a read-only list of strings that I access in my program. It used to be only Android, so I just copied my text file over to a local Sqlite database to read from since at the time it was simpler.

Now that I'm moving my program to multiple platforms, I'm looking to see if maybe I overcomplicated things in my first attempt at this.

Basically I just have a very long list of small strings in a text file. I need to access them, and be able to randomly select lines. I do not need the ability to write back to the file.

Does Java have a way I could do this from within the code? Or is an external database still the best way to navigate this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It may help to say how big is the list of strings (number and total size), and how you access each string, i.e. simple index lookup, query, substring search.

Comment: Thousands of string entries, but I only access them at random. So a random index would work well. No searching is needed at all.

Comment: Even thousands of strings isn't much data, unless they're unusually long.  I'd suggest XML, and loading them all into memory when you start up.  Presumably Java has built-in XML support.